# AWS SWF - IllegalStateException: No context found. (method called outside the workflow definition)

Tags: amazon-web-services, flash, amazon-swf

I am writing an AWS SWF application using the flow framework. Getting an `IllegalStateException: No context Found. It means that the method is called outside of the workflow definition code.` while calling the following code:

```
private DecisionContextProvider contextProvider
     = new DecisionContextProviderImpl();

private WorkflowClock clock
     = contextProvider.getDecisionContext().getWorkflowClock();
```

Why am I getting this error and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown by `getDecisionContext()` when you call it outside of a workflow (it should only be called somewhere in the call hierarchy of your workflow implementation - ie, your `WorkflowImpl` ).

To avoid getting that error, you should only call `getDecisionContext()` while inside of a workflow or its constructor.  The object only gets set in those circumstances (by the simple workflow framework), and doesn't exist outside of workflow execution, hence the `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: was this the right answer @Jatin? I am running this method inside the workflow class and still getting the exception :(